# PHP Strtotime with Variables and without time

Tags: php, strtotime

I am using this notation of `strtotime` without setting time which seems to work fine but I was wondering if it's valid or if there is a more appropriate syntax.

```
$now = time();
$date = strtotime("$sryear-$srmon-$srday ");
$datediff = $date - $now;
```

I am just calculating the difference between today and the set date and I would like to ignore time. `$sryear, $srmon, $srday` are variables containing year, month, day respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');
$datediff = abs(strtotime($now) - strtotime($sryear."-".$srmon".-".$srday));
$days = $datediff/(60 * 60 * 24);

printf("Days difference between %s and %s = %d", $sryear."-".$srmon".-".$srday, $now, $days);
```